# JAVA cardLayout. how to call a card from different classes

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

i have a program with a frame that contains a main panel with the cardlayout layout, and i want it to display different cards/panel.

In my case i'm really struggling to call a new card from a button action listener.

I want a new card to appear after i click on a button but none of the codes i put in my action listener displayed the card i wanted.

I know my actionListener work because i did a println inside.

here's my code. i got rid of anything that was unnecessary so it's easier to read. Thanks for the help!

i'll take all advices about code structuration

the mainFrame :

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

final static String CONNEXION_VIEW = "connexionView"; 
final static String CONNEXION_FAILED_VIEW = "connexionRefusee"; 

public MainFrame()
{
    super();
    initialize();
}


private void initialize()
{
    getMainPanel();

    add(getMainPanel());

}

CardLayout cardLayout;
public CardLayout getCardLayout()
{
    if (cardLayout == null)
    {
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    }
    return cardLayout;
}


JPanel mainPanel;
public JPanel getMainPanel()
{
    if (mainPanel == null)
    {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        mainPanel.setLayout(getCardLayout());

        mainPanel.add(CONNEXION_VIEW, getConnexionView());
        mainPanel.add(CONNEXION_FAILED_VIEW, getConnexionFailedView());

    }
    return mainPanel;
}

ConnexionView connexionView;
protected ConnexionView getConnexionView()
{
    if (connexionView == null)
    {
        connexionView = new ConnexionView();
    }
    return connexionView;
}

ConnexionFailedView connexionFailedView;
protected ConnexionFailedView getConnexionFailedView()
{
    if (connexionFailedView == null)
    {
        connexionFailedView = new ConnexionFailedView();
    }
    return connexionFailedView;
}
```

the connexion view, the one with the button to click with the action listener where i want to put my code

```
public class ConnexionView extends JPanel{

GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();

private JButton btnConnexion;

Dimension dimensionBouton = new Dimension(170, 30);

public ConnexionView()
{
    super();
    initialise();
}

private void initialise()
{
    setLayout(gbl);

    GridBagConstraints gbcbtnConnexion = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbcbtnConnexion.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbcbtnConnexion.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gbcbtnConnexion.gridx = 1;
    gbcbtnConnexion.gridy = 2;
    add(getBtnConnexion(), gbcbtnConnexion);
}

private JButton getBtnConnexion()
{
    if (btnConnexion == null)
    {
        btnConnexion = new JButton("Connexion");
        btnConnexion.setPreferredSize(dimensionBouton);
        btnConnexion.setMinimumSize(dimensionBouton);

        btnConnexion.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                /////code to display the connexion_Failed_View

                System.out.println("test");
            }
        });
    }
    return btnConnexion;
}
```

}

and the connexion failed view, the one i want to display after the button is clicked

```
public class ConnexionFailedView extends JPanel{

public ConnexionFailedView()
{
    super();
    initialise();
}

private void initialise()
{
    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to keep the component in your Button somehow, so you can access it.

```
class ConnexionView {
    private JComponent mainPanel;
    public ConnexionView(JComponent mp) { mainPanel = mp; }
}
```

Obviously, that means the MainFrame needs to pass it then.

Now, the listener can do

```
// it would be cleaner if you passed the layout in the constructor as well
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayoutManager();
cl.show(mainPanel, MainFrame.CONNEXION_FAILED_VIEW);
```

Comment: @Clement Great. Feel free to select the checkmark next to the answer to tag it as Answered :)